# How limit the storage space for a user?

Tags: debian, storage

I want to have a user that can store a limited amount on its account.

Comment: I believe you are looking for something on [this](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/47/Limiting_your_users_use_of_disk_space_with_quotas) line.

Comment: The `quota_v2` module mentioned in the above link is available in raspbian ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need disk quotas. See this https://www.debian-administration.org/article/47/Limiting_your_users_use_of_disk_space_with_quotas